Can a screenshot be resubmitted for a different Screenshot of the Week?
If a screenshot is submitted for Screenshot of the Week and it doesn't win, are we allowed to resubmit that screenshot for a different week later on? In particular, if a screenshot is originally submitted for a "themeless" week, but it matches the theme of a contest held later on.

There is no rule saying you can't.
I'd say it may be frowned upon by some, but I think the scenario you described makes a good case for reusing a screenshot.
I would say limit reusing screenshots to once (two total times posted), and if your screenshot previously won a week, I would not use it again.

You and I discussed this a few months back SotW #107, and the upvotes to comments implies that the community seems to be generally ok this

@Wondercricket I thought I talked about this before with someone!
